# Can we avoid repeating table joins by views in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, view

I have some queries, all of them work on the same table joins. Their difference is in the where clause. I want not to repeat table joins for each query. So I created a view and wrote table joins in it and used it for each query. My question is: does using views really avoid repeating table joins? Or it is the same as writing a function and putting the table joins in it and then calling it for each query? I am using laravel.

I tried to avoid repeating table joins by creating a view.

Comment: Can you explain exactly why you are concerned by repeating table joins?

Comment: Time consuming. Since the number of queries that use these tables joins are high, maybe repeating join causes the high runtime for huge data

Comment: you can take a look on materiazed views https://www.halcyon.hr/posts/materialized-caches-in-laravel/

Comment: Thsnks a lot. I will search about it

Answer (score 0):

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)), a view is the result set of a stored query on the data, which the database users can query just as they would in a persistent database collection object.

Therefore, by calling a view in a code, you're executing a stored query.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know a way to store the tables join result and use it several times in laravel?

Comment: Your best bet would to use some caching solution like Redis or Memcached.